# Como criar um círculo de progresso?

Tags: java, swing

Estou querendo fazer um progresso em circulo igual a esse:

[image: exemplo]

Em Java, eu só consegui achar coisa sobre `JProgressBar`.

Comment: Está ai uma coisa interessante de se fazer em java!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe a classe [**`AnimatedIcon`**](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/) — não padrão na plataforma Java — que aparentemente serve para o que você está querendo fazer, não sei se visualmente ficará como você espera mas a ideia de exibir um círculo para informar que algo está sendo carregado é a mesma.

A forma mais simples (e também a qual utilizo) para esse tipo de situação é simplesmente inserir uma imagem animada com extensão **.gif** em um **`JLabel`**. Por meio do método [**`setIcon()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) você pode fazer isso.

Existem vários sites que fornecem esses círculos de *loading* pela internet, o Google pode te ajudar a encontrar um que atenda as suas necessidades. O [Preloaders](http://preloaders.net/) e o [SpiffyGif](http://spiffygif.com/) são bons e permitem customizar algumas opções existentes, acabei fazendo um exemplo bem rápido no primeiro site para testar:

[image: loading]

Tendo essa imagem, basta colocá-la como um recurso no seu projeto. Então pode criar um método para retornar um **`JPanel`/`JLabel`** contendo essa imagem como ícone, isso quem define é você. Como não foi especificado nada na pergunta, criei um exemplo com a imagem acima sendo inserida diretamente no `JFrame`, o resultado é esse:

[image: preview]

E segue o código:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.URL;

public class LoadingTest extends JFrame {

    public LoadingTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        // Propriedades do JFrame.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(150, 150);


        // Obtendo o recurso (no caso, a imagem de 'loading').
        ImageIcon loadingImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("loading.GIF"));

        // Instanciando um novo JLabel e definindo a imagem encontrada como ícone.
        JLabel loadingLabel = new JLabel();
        loadingLabel.setIcon(loadingImage);

        // Inserindo o JLabel no Frame.
        getContentPane().add(loadingLabel);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new LoadingTest("Testando Loading").setVisible(true);
        }); 
    }
}
```